# How to find the Nearest (day of the week) for a given date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I been practicing queries, and my current scenario is to find the nearest Saturday for a given date. After i got the logic down, i came up with a, whats looks like a long and messy query. And I was wondering if there is a way to simplify this. 
Here's my query

```
DECLARE @DATE DATE
SET @DATE ='2013-09-13'

IF              DATENAME(DW,@DATE) = 'SUNDAY'
    BEGIN 
        SELECT  DATEADD(DAY,-1,@DATE) AS DATE, 'IS THE NEAREST SATURDAY'
    END
ELSE IF         DATENAME(DW,@DATE) = 'MONDAY'
    BEGIN 
        SELECT  DATEADD(DAY,-2,@DATE) AS DATE, 'IS THE NEAREST SATURDAY'
    END
ELSE IF         DATENAME(DW,@DATE) = 'TUESDAY'
    BEGIN 
        SELECT  DATEADD(DAY,-3,@DATE) AS DATE, 'IS THE NEAREST SATURDAY'
    END
ELSE IF         DATENAME(DW,@DATE) = 'WEDNESDAY'
    BEGIN 
        SELECT  DATEADD(DAY,3,@DATE) AS DATE, 'IS THE NEAREST SATURDAY'
    END
ELSE IF         DATENAME(DW,@DATE) = 'THURSDAY'
    BEGIN 
        SELECT  DATEADD(DAY,2,@DATE) AS DATE, 'IS THE NEAREST SATURDAY'
    END
ELSE IF         DATENAME(DW,@DATE) = 'FRIDAY'
    BEGIN 
        SELECT  DATEADD(DAY,1,@DATE) AS DATE, 'IS THE NEAREST SATURDAY'
    END
ELSE IF         DATENAME(DW,@DATE) = 'SATURDAY'
    BEGIN
        SELECT  CONVERT(NVARCHAR,@DATE) + ' IS SATURDAY' AS DATE_DOW
    END
```

As we can see the query is long and runs multiple IFs to look for TRUE condition.
Please don't write the query, just hints. I would like to work on the query myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my hint without answering, as you requested:

Consider date manipulation, using current date (you can use `GETDATE()` or your date variable), `DATEADD()` and `DATEDIFF()` can be used to write this in a couple lines.

If you just want to simplify your method you could use a `CASE` statement:

```
DECLARE @date DATE = '2013-09-13'
SELECT CASE WHEN DATENAME(DW,@DATE) = 'SUNDAY' THEN  CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-3,@DATE) AS VARCHAR(12)) + ' IS THE NEAREST SATURDAY'
            WHEN DATENAME(DW,@DATE) = 'MONDAY' THEN CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-2,@DATE) AS VARCHAR(12)) + ' IS THE NEAREST SATURDAY'
            WHEN DATENAME(DW,@DATE) = 'TUESDAY' THEN CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-1,@DATE) AS VARCHAR(12)) + ' IS THE NEAREST SATURDAY'
            WHEN DATENAME(DW,@DATE) = 'WEDNESDAY' THEN CAST(DATEADD(DAY,1,@DATE) AS VARCHAR(12)) + ' IS THE NEAREST SATURDAY'
            WHEN DATENAME(DW,@DATE) = 'THURSDAY' THEN CAST(DATEADD(DAY,2,@DATE) AS VARCHAR(12)) + ' IS THE NEAREST SATURDAY'
            WHEN DATENAME(DW,@DATE) = 'FRIDAY' THEN CAST(DATEADD(DAY,3,@DATE) AS VARCHAR(12)) + ' IS THE NEAREST SATURDAY'
            ELSE CONVERT(NVARCHAR,@DATE) + ' IS SATURDAY'
       END
```

To clarify on the method I was hinting at and Sparky posted, you need to adjust `DATEFIRST` to make this work, it works for whichever day is the first day of the week, Saturday is the 7th day of the week, so:

```
SET DATEFIRST 7
DECLARE @date DATE = '2013-09-21'
SELECT DATEADD(day,7-DATEPART(weekday,@date),@date)
```

Comment: Thanks Goat CO, MY original query had CASE statements. But since THEN[can have result only] and not an expression, it was not working, so i tried setting up multiple variables for each WHEN condition, which seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select dateAdd(dd,7-DATEPART(dw,getDate()),GETDATE())
```

**datePart(dw,...)** returns day of the week for current date.

**7 - that number**, returns number of days until Saturday

Add the result to the date to get the next Saturday...

Similar logic if you need to go back to previous Saturday

Sql Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/61998/2

Comment: Thank you for the query, and the explanation.

Comment: Goat CO - Works fine as written in SQL 2008   Just wanted to give op another way to solve this question

Answer (score 0):

Well not exactly an answer, but an alternative

```
    DECLARE @DATE DATE,
    @SUN DATE,
    @MON DATE,
    @TUE DATE,
    @WED DATE,
    @THU DATE,
    @FRI DATE,
    @SAT DATE

           SET @DATE = '2013-09-14'

    SET @SUN = DATEADD(DAY,-1,@DATE)
    SET @MON = DATEADD(DAY,-1,@DATE)
    SET @TUE = DATEADD(DAY,-2,@DATE)
    SET @WED = DATEADD(DAY,-3,@DATE)
    SET @THU = DATEADD(DAY,2,@DATE)
    SET @FRI = DATEADD(DAY,1,@DATE)
    SET @SAT = DATEADD(DAY,0,@DATE)

    SELECT CASE 
        WHEN DATENAME(DW,@DATE) = 'SUNDAY'
        THEN @SUN
        WHEN DATENAME(DW,@DATE) = 'MONDAY'
        THEN @MON
        WHEN DATENAME(DW,@DATE) = 'TUESDAY'
        THEN @TUE
        WHEN DATENAME(DW,@DATE) = 'WEDNESDAY'
        THEN @WED
        WHEN DATENAME(DW,@DATE) = 'THURSDAY'
        THEN @THU
        WHEN DATENAME(DW,@DATE) = 'FRIDAY'
        THEN @FRI
        ELSE @SAT
    END
```