# Passing in Week Day name to get nearest date in SQL

Tags: sql-server, date

I'm working on a query that deals with a frequency value (i.e. Mondays, Tuesdays, etc. - Think assignments).

So in my query I currently have a result of

```
jobId:1, personId:100, frequencyVal: 'Mondays'
jobId:2, personId:101, frequencyVal: 'Saturdays'
```

What I need is the next the 4 future(or current) dates for the frequencyVal.

So if today is 1/3/2015

I would need my result set to be

```
jobId:1, personId:100, frequencyVal: 'Mondays', futureDates: '1/5,1/12,1/19,1/26'
jobId:2, personId:102, frequencyVal: 'Saturdays', futureDates: '1/3,1/10,1/17,1/24'
```

I was looking at the following post:
[How to find the Nearest (day of the week) for a given date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18791270/how-to-find-the-nearest-day-of-the-week-for-a-given-date)

But that sets it for a specific date.  And I'm looking at this being a web application and I want the dates for the current date.  So if I try to run this query next Tuesday the future dates for `jobId:1 would remove the 1/5 and add the 2/2`.

Is there a way to pass in a weekday value to get the next nearest date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample table

```
create table #t
(
    jobId int,
    personId int,
    frequencyVal varchar(10)
);

insert into #t values (1,100,'Mondays'),(2,101,'Saturdays');
```

**QUERY 1 : Select nearest 4 week of days in current month for particular week day**

```
-- Gets first day of month
DECLARE @FIRSTDAY DATE=DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0)

;WITH  CTE as
(
     -- Will find all dates in current month
     SELECT CAST(@FIRSTDAY AS DATE) as DATES
     UNION ALL
     SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,DATES)    
     FROM    CTE
     WHERE   DATES < DATEADD(MONTH,1,@FIRSTDAY)
 )
,CTE2 AS
(
   -- Join the #t table with  CTE on the datename+'s' 
   SELECT jobId,personId,frequencyVal,DATES,
   -- Get week difference for each weekday        
   DATEDIFF(WEEK,DATES,GETDATE()) WEEKDIFF,
   -- Count the number of weekdays in a month
   COUNT(DATES) OVER(PARTITION BY DATENAME(WEEKDAY,CTE.DATES)) WEEKCOUNT
   FROM CTE
   JOIN #t ON DATENAME(WEEKDAY,CTE.DATES)+'s' = #t.frequencyVal 
   WHERE MONTH(DATES)= MONTH(GETDATE())   
)
-- Converts to CSV and make sure that only nearest 4 week of days are generated for month
SELECT  DISTINCT C2.jobId,C2.personId,frequencyVal,
         SUBSTRING(
        (SELECT ', ' + CAST(DATEPART(MONTH,DATES) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/'  + 
                       CAST(DATEPART(DAY,DATES) AS VARCHAR(2))
        FROM CTE2 
        WHERE C2.jobId=jobId AND C2.personId=personId AND C2.frequencyVal=frequencyVal AND
                       ((WEEKDIFF<3 AND WEEKDIFF>-3 AND WEEKCOUNT = 5) OR WEEKCOUNT <= 4)
        ORDER BY CTE2.DATES
        FOR XML PATH('')),2,200000) futureDates
FROM CTE2 C2
```

- **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/41bcd/2)**

For example, in Query2 the nearest date(here we take example as Saturday) of

```
2015-Jan-10 will be 01/03,01/10,01/17,01/24
2015-Jan-24 will be 01/10,01/17,01/24,01/31
```

**QUERY 2 : Select next 4 week's dates for particular week day irrelevant of month**

```
;WITH  CTE as
(
     -- Will find the next 4 week details
     SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) as DATES
     UNION ALL
     SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,DATES)    
     FROM    CTE
     WHERE   DATES < DATEADD(DAY,28,GETDATE())
 )
,CTE2 AS
(
   -- Join the #t table with  CTE on the datename+'s' 
   SELECT jobId,personId,frequencyVal, DATES,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DATENAME(WEEKDAY,CTE.DATES) ORDER BY CTE.DATES) DATECNT
   FROM CTE
   JOIN #t ON DATENAME(WEEKDAY,CTE.DATES)+'s' = #t.frequencyVal  
)
-- Converts to CSV and make sure that only 4 days are generated for month
SELECT  DISTINCT C2.jobId,C2.personId,frequencyVal,   
        SUBSTRING(
        (SELECT ', ' + CAST(DATEPART(MONTH,DATES) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/'  + 
                       CAST(DATEPART(DAY,DATES) AS VARCHAR(2))
        FROM CTE2 
        WHERE C2.jobId=jobId AND C2.personId=personId AND C2.frequencyVal=frequencyVal 
              AND DATECNT < 5
        ORDER BY CTE2.DATES
        FOR XML PATH('')),2,200000) futureDates
        FROM CTE2 C2
```

- **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/41bcd/3)**

The following would be the output if the `GETDATE()` (if its Saturday) is

```
2015-01-05 - 1/10, 1/17, 1/24, 1/31
2015-01-24 - 1/24, 1/31, 2/7, 2/14
```

Comment: please note that return value of `DATETIME` is dependend on current language setting, so this might not return English names on all systems (if not set explicitly)

Comment: Yes. Thats right. But the values of the days from the part of OP is in english. @DrCopyPaste

Comment: True, but OP's values likely do not come from `DATENAME`-usages, just assuming OP's DBMS has the correct default values could be dangerous ;) (for example I use English names and titles whereever I can, but still I have a completely different language default setting)

Comment: @SarathAvanavu - you gave me 2 ways of doing it.  Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. I have also answered to your other question with 3 methods. You can also check that. And thank you for you upvote and answer :) @webdad3

Answer (score 2):

I prefer a calendar table for this kind of query. Actually, I prefer a calendar table over date functions for most queries. Here's a minimal one. The one I use in production has more columns and more rows. (100 years of data is only 37k rows.)

```
create table calendar (
  cal_date date not null primary key,
  day_of_week varchar(15)
  );

insert into calendar (cal_date) values 
('2015-01-01'), ('2015-01-02'), ('2015-01-03'), ('2015-01-04'),
('2015-01-05'), ('2015-01-06'), ('2015-01-07'), ('2015-01-08'),
('2015-01-09'), ('2015-01-10'), ('2015-01-11'), ('2015-01-12'),
('2015-01-13'), ('2015-01-14'), ('2015-01-15'), ('2015-01-16'),
('2015-01-17'), ('2015-01-18'), ('2015-01-19'), ('2015-01-20'),
('2015-01-21'), ('2015-01-22'), ('2015-01-23'), ('2015-01-24'),
('2015-01-25'), ('2015-01-26'), ('2015-01-27'), ('2015-01-28'),
('2015-01-29'), ('2015-01-30'), ('2015-01-31'),

('2015-02-01'), ('2015-02-02'), ('2015-02-03'), ('2015-02-04'),
('2015-02-05'), ('2015-02-06'), ('2015-02-07'), ('2015-02-08'),
('2015-02-09'), ('2015-02-10'), ('2015-02-11'), ('2015-02-12'),
('2015-02-13'), ('2015-02-14'), ('2015-02-15'), ('2015-02-16'),
('2015-02-17'), ('2015-02-18'), ('2015-02-19'), ('2015-02-20'),
('2015-02-21'), ('2015-02-22'), ('2015-02-23'), ('2015-02-24'),
('2015-02-25'), ('2015-02-26'), ('2015-02-27'), ('2015-02-28')
;

update calendar
set day_of_week = datename(weekday, cal_date);

alter table calendar 
alter column day_of_week varchar(15) not null;

alter table calendar
add constraint cal_date_matches_dow
check (datename(weekday, cal_date) = day_of_week);

create index day_of_week_ix on calendar (day_of_week);
```

Set the privileges so that

- everyone can select, but
- almost nobody can insert new rows, and
- even fewer people can delete rows.

(Or write a constraint that can guarantee there are no gaps. I *think* you can do that in SQL Server.)

You can select the next four Mondays after today with a very simple SQL statement. (The current date is 2015-01-05, which is a Monday.)

```
select top 4 cal_date
from calendar
where cal_date > convert(date, getdate())
  and day_of_week = 'Monday'
order by cal_date;
```

```
CAL_DATE
--
2015-01-12
2015-01-19
2015-01-26
2015-02-02
```

For me, this is a huge advantage. No procedural code. Simple SQL that is obviously right. Big win.

Comment: I do like the direction you are heading. Better to keep it simple than anything else.  I imagine there is code out there that builds a calendar type of table(s) that account for leap years and such.  Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: The simplest is probably just a spreadsheet. If you add columns to a calendar table, make sure you *also* add CHECK constraints.

Comment: please note that return value of `DATETIME` is dependend on current language setting, so this might not return English names on all systems (if not set explicitly)

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in function to do it. But you can try this, you may place it inside a Scalar-Valued Function:

```
DECLARE @WeekDay VARCHAR(10) = 'Monday';
DECLARE @WeekDayInt INT;

SELECT @WeekDayInt = CASE @WeekDay
                     WHEN 'SUNDAY'    THEN 1 
                     WHEN 'MONDAY'    THEN 2 
                     WHEN 'TUESDAY'   THEN 3 
                     WHEN 'WEDNESDAY' THEN 4 
                     WHEN 'THURSDAY'  THEN 5 
                     WHEN 'FRIDAY'    THEN 6
                     WHEN 'SATURDAY'  THEN 7 END

SELECT CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) + @WeekDayInt) % 7, GETDATE())) AS NearestDate
```

**UPDATE:**

Looks like radar was right, here's the solution:

```
DECLARE @WeekDay    VARCHAR(10) = 'Monday';
DECLARE @WeekDayInt INT;
DECLARE @Date       DATETIME = GETDATE();

SELECT @WeekDayInt = CASE @WeekDay
                     WHEN 'SUNDAY'    THEN 1 
                     WHEN 'MONDAY'    THEN 2 
                     WHEN 'TUESDAY'   THEN 3 
                     WHEN 'WEDNESDAY' THEN 4 
                     WHEN 'THURSDAY'  THEN 5 
                     WHEN 'FRIDAY'    THEN 6
                     WHEN 'SATURDAY'  THEN 7 END
DECLARE @Diff INT = DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @Date) - @WeekDayInt;
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, CASE WHEN @Diff >= 0 THEN 7 - @Diff ELSE ABS(@Diff) END, @Date)) AS NearestDate
```

Comment: This might not work tomorrow, as it is coded specific to today being Saturday

Comment: @radar - what are your suggestions then to make it work for any day of the week?

Comment: @webdad3 @radar SQL Server uses `@@DATEFIRST`s value to determine the `WEEKDAY`-value of `DATETIME`s, you can get the current setting with `SELECT @@DATEFIRST` and set a new one with `SET DATEFIRST <intVal>` also see [here](http://blog.kroneck.de/en/post/2010/04/18/Determine-the-Weekday-of-a-given-date-in-T-SQL-independant-of-SQL-Server-Language-and-Settings.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this - based on [king.code's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27757509/3527240) answer to get the nearest date.

```
create table #t
(
    jobId int,
    personId int,
    frequencyVal varchar(10)
);

insert into #t values (1,100,'Mondays'),(2,101,'Saturdays');

WITH cte(n) AS
(
    SELECT 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n+1 FROM cte WHERE n < 3
)

select #t.jobId, #t.personId, #t.frequencyVal, STUFF(a.d, 1, 1, '') AS FutureDates
from #t
cross apply (SELECT CASE #t.frequencyVal
                         WHEN 'SUNDAYS'    THEN 1 
                         WHEN 'MONDAYS'    THEN 2 
                         WHEN 'TUESDAYS'   THEN 3 
                         WHEN 'WEDNESDAYS' THEN 4 
                         WHEN 'THURSDAYS'  THEN 5 
                         WHEN 'FRIDAYS'    THEN 6
                         WHEN 'SATURDAYS'  THEN 7 
                    END)tranlationWeekdays(n)
cross apply (select ',' +  CONVERT(varchar(10),  CONVERT(date,dateadd(WEEK, cte.n,CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) + tranlationWeekdays.n) % 7, GETDATE()))))) from cte FOR XML PATH('')) a(d);

drop table #t;
```

Comment: Wow!  That gave me EXACTLY what I was looking for.  I'm going to have to research STUFF and cross apply.  That seems pretty awesome!

Comment: It is! Learned it prox 2 weeks ago and I find it very powerful (cross apply).

Comment: I don't understand what was wrong with my answer. You just used my code to create your "own" answer. This is completely unfair.

Comment: You answered partially. You gave an answer to get the nearest date but not to get the future 4.

Comment: @Hatsjoem have a look to the question he made. Hint: it has a question mark.

Comment: @king.code I know, but I based my answer on the desired resultset.

Comment: This might not work tomorrow, as it is coded specific to today being Saturday

Comment: @king.code - your answer was very good, but Hatsjoem was complete (giving me everything).  I can't mark both answers as the answer.  I can only upvote them.  I do appreciate your answer as it was giving me a direction to go off of.  I appreciate the time you put into your answer.

Comment: @webdad3 that's not the point. I understand that you have to accept the answer that you've actually used. I just think that use someone's answers to create "own" answers on the same question is not correct.

Comment: @Hatsjoem - it looks like radar was right.  The future dates are off.  For example Saturdays are set for tomorrow (1/5).  All the dates are off.  Any ideas?

Comment: @webdad3 @Hatsjoem SQL Server uses `@@DATEFIRST`s value to determine the `WEEKDAY`-value of `DATETIME`s, you can get the current setting with `SELECT @@DATEFIRST` and set a new one with `SET DATEFIRST <intVal>` also see [here](http://blog.kroneck.de/en/post/2010/04/18/Determine-the-Weekday-of-a-given-date-in-T-SQL-independant-of-SQL-Server-Language-and-Settings.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This is a simpler way I think, and I think it fits your requirements.

Note that I have changed your `frequency_val` column to an integer that represents the day of the week from SQL servers perspective and added a calculated column to illustrate how you can easily derive the day name from that.

```
declare @t table
(
    jobId int,
    personId int,
    --frequencyVal varchar(10)
    frequency_val int,
    frequency_day as datename(weekday,frequency_val -1) + 's'
);
```

declare @num_occurances int = 4
declare @from_date date = dateadd(dd,3,getdate()) -- this will allow you to play with the date simply by changing the increment value

insert into @t 
values 
    (1,100,1),--'Mondays'),
    (2,101,6),--'Saturdays');
    (3,101,7),--'Saturdays');
    (4,100,2)--'Mondays'),
--select * from @t

;with r_cte (days_ahead, occurance_date)
as (select 0, convert(date,@from_date,121)
    union all
    select r_cte.days_ahead +1, convert(date,dateadd(DD, r_cte.days_ahead+1, @from_date),121)
    from r_cte
    where r_cte.days_ahead < 7 * @num_occurances
    )
select t.*, r_cte.occurance_date
from
    @t t
    inner join r_cte
        on DATEPART(WEEKDAY, dateadd(dd,@@DATEFIRST - 1 ,r_cte.occurance_date)) = t.frequency_val

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
DECLARE @YEAR INT=2015
DECLARE @MONTH INT=1
DECLARE @DAY INT=1
DECLARE @DATE DATE = (SELECT DateFromParts(@Year, @Month, @Day))
DECLARE @TOTAL_DAYS INT =(SELECT DatePart(DY, @DATE));

WITH CTE1
     AS (SELECT T_DAY=(SELECT DateName(DW, @DATE)),
                @DATE AS T_DATE,
                @DAY  AS T_DDAY
         UNION ALL
         SELECT T_DAY=(SELECT DateName(DW, DateAdd(DAY, T_DDAY + 1, @DATE))),
                DateAdd(DAY, T_DDAY + 1, @DATE) AS T_DATE,
                T_DDAY + 1
         FROM   CTE1
         WHERE  T_DDAY + 1 <= 364)
SELECT DISTINCT T_DAY,
       Stuff((SELECT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), T_DATE)
              FROM   CTE1 A
              WHERE  A.T_DAY=CTE1.T_DAY AND A.T_DATE > GetDate() AND A.T_DATE<(DATEADD(WEEK,4,GETDATE())) 
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS FUTURE
FROM   CTE1
ORDER  BY T_DAY
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 365)
```

Answer (score 0):

*Having seen the use of `DATENAME` in some of the answers already given, I'd like to point out that return values of `DATENAME` might vary depending on your [current language setting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174398.aspx), but you can save the current language setting and ensure usage of `us_english` so you can be confident to use English weekday names.*

Now here is my slightly different approach to get the 4 next dates that fall on a certain (known) weekday, using a user defined table valued function that allows to create a number sequence table *(yes this is a pretty dull function, you have to pass MaxValue greater MinValue, but that could be easily enhanced, if needed, but hey, it does the job)*. Using that function span a table over 28 values *(next 28 days should indeed include the next 4 relevant weekdays ;))*, apply `DATEADD` on `GETDATE` and reduce the result set with `WHERE` to only those values that have the right weekday:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetIntSequence(@MinValue INT, @MaxValue INT)
RETURNS @retSequence TABLE
(
    IntValue INT NOT NULL
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @i INT = (SELECT @MinValue)

    WHILE @i <= @MaxValue
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @retSequence (IntValue) SELECT @i

        SELECT @i = @i + 1
    END

    RETURN
END

GO
DECLARE @weekDay NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Monday'   --(or Tuesday, wednesday, ...)

--save current language setting
DECLARE @languageBackup NVARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT @@LANGUAGE)
--ensure us english language setting for reliable weekday names
SET LANGUAGE us_english;


SELECT FourWeeks.SomeDay FROM
    (
        SELECT
                DATEADD(DAY, IntValue, GETDATE()) AS SomeDay
            FROM dbo.GetIntSequence(1, 28)
    ) AS FourWeeks
    WHERE DATENAME(WEEKDAY, SomeDay) = @weekDay

--restore old language setting
SET LANGUAGE @languageBackup;

GO

DROP FUNCTION dbo.GetIntSequence
```