# SQL Server : finding the nearest Tuesday

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

How to find the nearest Tuesday by given date previous only in SQL Server?

Example: today is `2018-09-09`, the result should be `2018-09-04`.

Comment: Question already asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18791270/how-to-find-the-nearest-day-of-the-week-for-a-given-date

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the Nearest (day of the week) for a given date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18791270/how-to-find-the-nearest-day-of-the-week-for-a-given-date)

Answer (score 0):

use `case when` and `datepart` function and conditionally find nearest Tuesday

```
   select case datepart(dw,getdate()) when 7 then DATEADD(day, -4, getdate()) 
when 1 then DATEADD(day, -5, getdate())
when 2 then DATEADD(day, -6, getdate())
when 3 then DATEADD(day, -7, getdate())
when 4  then DATEADD(day, -1, getdate())
when 5  then DATEADD(day, -2, getdate())
when 6  then DATEADD(day, -3, getdate())
else getdate() end;
```

Comment: hard-coded for Tuesday, a general solution where the target day of week is a better solution

Comment: @Moho read question op finding answer for nearest tuesday from any given date and appreciate your downvote  as you describe reaosn of downvote

Comment: Hi Akh, your answer is nice but gives the next tuesday. Please refer : http://rextester.com/REKHK7643

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan thanks i thought op wanted given date nearest future or previous but thanks again im goin to edit only for previous

Comment: `DATEPART( dw, ... )` result is based on the value of `@@DATEFIRST`; shouldn't assume `7` is the start of the week.  Adjust via `( 7 - @@DATEFIRST + @targetDayOfWeek ) % 7 + 1` where `@targetDayOfWeek` is `2` for Tuesday

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I misread the question but I'll leave this here in case someone else might find it educational (it also demonstrates how `DATEPART( dw, ... )` result can differ by server so hard-coding values as in the above answer may lead to erroneous results depending on environment) - this will calculated the closest date to a specified day of week (whereas the question asked for the previous Tuesday, specifically)...

You're given a date.  You want to find the nearest Tuesday so you'll first need to figure out what day of the week the given date represents.  Google "mssql day of week" and the [first hit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is the function you can use to get the day of week.  It will be in an integer format, so you'll need to reference [which numbers represents which days of the week](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

The result will be based on the value of @@DATEFIRST which defines the first day of the week (and the results are a one-based index), so you will need to adjust your target day of week value to align with the server's `@@DATEFIRST` value.  You can do this by subtracting `@@DATEFIRST` from `7`, adding the target day of week value (1: Monday through 7: Sunday), modulo the result by `7` and add `1` to keep at a one-based index:

```
( 7 - @@DATEFIRST + @targetDayOfWeek ) % 7 + 1
```

Once you know what day of the week your target date is and what number represents Tuesday, you then calculate the difference in days.  If the magnitude is greater than 3, adjust by adding or subtracting 7 to fit into the range [-3, 3].

```
create function dbo.CalculateClosestDayOfWeekDate
(
    @fromDate DATETIME,
    @targetDayOfWeek int -- 1: Monday ... 7: Sunday
)
returns DATETIME
as
begin
    -- AdjustedTargetDayOfWeek: ( 7 - @@DATEFIRST + @targetDayOfWeek ) % 7 + 1
    -- FromDateDayOfWeek: DATEPART( dw, @fromDate )
    -- DayOfWeekDiff = AdjustedTargetDayOfWeek - FromDateDayOfWeek

    declare @daysToAdd int
    set @daysToAdd = ( ( 7 - @@DATEFIRST + @targetDayOfWeek ) % 7 + 1 ) - DATEPART( dw, @fromDate )

    -- if the nearest previous day-of-week is all that's wanted,
    --   replace the below block with `if( 0 < @daysToAdd)`
    --   and subtract 7 from @daysToAdd if true
    if( 3 < ABS( @daysToAdd ) ) -- if magnitude greater than 3
    begin
        if( 3 < @daysToAdd ) -- if positive, subtract 7
        begin
            set @daysToAdd = @daysToAdd - 7
        end
        else -- negative, so add 7
        begin
            set @daysToAdd = @daysToAdd + 7
        end
    end

    return DATEADD( day, @daysToAdd, @fromDate )
end
go

declare @testData table
(
    FromDate dateTime,
    TargetDayOfWeek int
)

insert @testData values ( '2018-09-08', 2 ) -- target Tuesday from a Saturday
insert @testData values ( '2018-09-08', 3 ) -- target Wednesday from a Saturday
insert @testData values ( '2018-09-09', 3 ) -- target Wednesday from a Sunday
insert @testData values ( '2018-09-09', 4 ) -- target Thursday from a Sunday
insert @testData values ( '2018-09-10', 4 ) -- target Thursday from a Monday
insert @testData values ( '2018-09-10', 5 ) -- target Friday from a Monday

select
    td.FromDate
    , td.TargetDayOfWeek
    , dbo.CalculateClosestDayOfWeekDate( td.FromDate, td.TargetDayOfWeek ) ResultingDate
from
    @testData td
```

Results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try it.

```
select 
case when datepart(dw,getdate()) =7 
or datepart(dw,getdate()) =6 
or  datepart(dw,getdate()) =5 
or datepart(dw,getdate()) =4  
then DATEADD(day, 3-datepart(dw,getdate()) , getdate())
else  DATEADD(day, -4-datepart(dw,getdate()) , getdate())
end;
```